# How to make hadoop replication factor change for a file persistent

Tags: hadoop, replication

I have a query regarding hadoop replication.

I changed the replication factor of files in a particular directory in hadoop using the below mentioned command:

`hadoop dfs -setrep -R 3 -w /data/routing`

It was successful and it set the replication factor of all the files in this directory to `3`. However any new file being written under this directory continued to have default replication factor, i.e. `2`.

Is there any option to make this change persistent?

Actually I want all the new files being written under this directory only to always have the replication factor as `3`, irrespective of what is the default replication factor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something other than the default replication factor, you'll need to explicitly set the replication factor when you create the file(s).

Are the files under the directory created via a mapreduce job, or manually using some other process?

For mapreduce, just change/set the job configuration value for the default replication factor - `dfs.replication`. If you're creating the file(s) manually in some java code, then look at the API for [`FileSystem.create(Path, short)`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#create%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20short%29)